# Polyfills and package.json optionalDependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, polyfills

I'm working on a library that require some polyfills in some environments. Is correct to add the `polyfills` as `optionalDependencies` in the `package.jso` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is adding them in the dependencies and then in the code at runtime detect if needed and require them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I asked this question a long time ago but I still needed to find out :)