# Should polyfills be a dependency or a devDependency?

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, package

As explained by this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36602912/polyfills-and-package-json-optionaldependencies), polyfills should be in the dependency folder.

However, the [Array.find() polyfill](https://github.com/jsPolyfill/Array.prototype.find) has the following installation instructions.

> npm install --save-dev jspolyfill-array.prototype.find

Shouldn't I be installing this polyfill as a normal dependency?